# How to programmatically create forum topics using entity api?

Tags: entities, nodes

I used [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146790/how-to-programmatically-create-forums-and-containers-not-forum-topics) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321632/how-to-create-a-forum-topic-programmatically) to get started but I was trying to use only the entity API.

Here is my code. So far the node creation works but I'm not able to save the node under the correct tid.

```
global $user;
$properties = array(
'type' => 'forum',
'uid' => $user->uid,
'status' => 0
); 
$entity = entity_create('node', $properties);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
$wrapper->title = "My new forum topic";
$terms =  taxonomy_get_term_by_name ('General discussion','forums');

//$wrapper->taxonomy = $terms; //Doesnt work
//$wrapper->forum_tid = $terms->tid; //Doesnt work
//$wrapper->taxonomy_forums = $terms->tid; //Doesnt work

$wrapper->save();
```

Comment: `$wrapper->taxonomy_forums = $terms->tid` or `$wrapper->taxonomy_forums->set($terms->tid);` should work fine, assuming `$terms->tid` is valid

Comment: Thanks Clive, you've always got the right answer or a much needed sanity check!!

Answer (score 1):

`$wrapper->taxonomy_forums = reset($terms)->tid;` works!! `taxonomy_get_term_by_name()` returns an array of objects keyed with extra dimension (I think its keyed by the tid). The wrapper's save method will call `forum_node_presave($node)` but will look in the wrong dimension for the tid if you don't get rid of it.