# Automake forum on node creation with rules

Tags: rules, nodes

I'm desperately trying to programmatically add a new forum (in the 194 tid specific container) on node creation with rules.

I run php script when adding new node with rules, but I'm really newbee with php. I'm trying to use form_forum_form and form_forum_submit putting this variables :

```
require_once 'modules/forum/forum.admin.inc';

$autoform = array( 
     'name' => '[node:title]',
    'description' => 'Forum du projet [node:title]',
    'tid' => 194,
    'weight' => 0,
);


$form = forum_form_forum($form, &$form_state, $edit = $autoform);  
forum_form_submit($form, &$form_state);
print_r(drupal_get_messages());
```

This link doesn't helped me and there is nowhere on the web where the answer is explicitely given.
[How to programmatically create forums and containers (not forum topics)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146790/how-to-programmatically-create-forums-and-containers-not-forum-topics)

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for any custom php here. Just the below steps.

In Rules actions,

1. Action 1: "Create a new entity > Taxonomy term"
2. Enter your title based on the created node and put it in the forum taxonomy
3. Action 2: "Set a data value > [entity-created:parent], Value: 194"

Comment: Really thanks, I had to set [forum-created:parent] as data for action 2. But works great !

Comment: @VictorBourgade if this answer help you don't forget check it as accepted, if you don't know how read this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Hey Niall, correct me if I'm wrong, but from your interesting answer I seemm to understand that there is no need for some PHP script (as in the question), or am I missing something? If I'm right, I think you should somehow indicate that also in your answer. PS to @AdrianCidAlmaguer : looks like your comment here has been obsoleted ...

Comment: Yeah, this answer covers the creation of a forum without the Php. I'll edit now.

Comment: Merci for clarifying Niall. But whillle you're at it, maybe you should also add like a note or so to explain that *If in Action 1 you don't use "entity_created", but "forum_created" instead, then that implies you also have to set **[forum-created:parent] as data for action 2*** (as in the comment from OPer below this answer). At least that's my best guess why OPer needed that minor tweak as in the comment, no?

Comment: Yep, you're right. I haven't been active on SE recently but will try to remember to do it tomorrow.